# Modelling Problem in Linear Programming Standard Form

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

I'm having a hard time setting this up, so that's what I need help with. The solving I understand. We’re making a drink with the following requirements:
at least 500 calories, at least 20 mg. of vitamin C, and at least 300 mg. of calcium.

We’d like to minimize the cost of the ingredients, subject to satisfying these nutrition
constraints. We are going to puree the ingredients together, and we can save any fractional
bananas and mangoes we don’t need for another drink or meal.

Here is the data:

- cost per 100 gms of item: milk: $0.24; mangoes: $0.67; orange juice:
  $0.31; bananas: $0.17
- vitamin C content per 100 gms of item: milk: 0mg; mangoes: 28mg;
  orange juice: 50mg; bananas: 8mg
- calcium content per 100 gms of item: milk: 130mg; mangoes: 10mg;
  orange juice: 11mg; bananas: 0 mg
- calories per 100 gms of item: milk: 50 kcal; mangoes: 70kcals; orange
  juice: 45kcals; bananas: 89 kcal

How can I model this situation as a linear programming problem in the following standard form:
minimize z = c^(T)X subject to AX ≥ b; X≥ 0.

Comment: Vimzy: Please don't edit out your question after it is answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the your the amount you have of your four items be $x_{milk}, x_{mango}, x_{orange}, x_{banana}$.

Your goal function, which you want to minimize is:
$$z = c_{milk}x_{milk} + c_{mango}x_{mango} + c_{orange}x_{orange} + c_{banana}x_{banana}$$
where $c_i$ is the cost of one unit of item $i$.

Your vitamin C content is:
$$v_{milk}x_{milk} + v_{mango}x_{mango} + v_{orange}x_{orange} + v_{banana}x_{banana} \geq 20$$
where $v_i$ is the amount of vitamin C per unit of item $i$.

Like wise for calcium and calories:
$$Ca_{milk}x_{milk} + Ca_{mangoes}x_{mango} + Ca_{orange}x_{orange} + v_{banana}x_{banana} \geq 300$$
$$Cal_{milk}x_{milk} + Cal_{mango}x_{mango} + Cal_{orange}x_{orange} + Cal_{banana}x_{banana} \geq 500$$

Inserting the given values yields:
$$\min z = 0.24x_{milk} + 0.67x_{mango} + 0.31x_{orange} + 0.17x_{banana}$$
satisfying:
$$\begin{align}
 & + 28x_{mango} & + 50x_{orange} & + 8x_{banana} & \geq 20 \\
130x_{milk} & + 10x_{mango} & + 11x_{orange} & {} & \geq 300 \\
50x_{milk} & + 70x_{mango} & + 45x_{orange} & + 89x_{banana} & \geq 500
\end{align}$$

And if you just put the coefficients in the expression for z in a vector $c$, the coefficients of the inequalities in a matrix $A$ and the right hand sides of the inequalities into a vector $b$, you have it on a standard form:
$$c = \begin{pmatrix}
0.24 \\ 0.67 \\ 0.31 \\ 0.17
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 28 & 50 & 8 \\
130 & 10 & 11 & 0 \\
60 & 70 & 45 & 89
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$b = \begin{pmatrix}
20 \\ 300 \\ 500
\end{pmatrix}$$

This problem, if I entered the values correctly has an optimal solution at approximately $x_{milk} = 2.31, x_{mango} = 0, x_{orange} = 0, x_{banana} = 4.1$, giving a cost of approximately 1.24, with a vitamin C content of 32 mg, a calcium content of 300 mg and an energy content of 500 kcal.